# Maven: dependency does not work as expected, is ignored in runtime

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am working with Maven and Spring Framework.

I am creating many projects how modules, such as:

- domain
- services definitions (interfaces)
- services implementations
- repositories definitions (interfaces)
- repositories implementations
- factories
- More…...

I have the **ProductRepository** interface within the package **com.manuel.jordan.model.repository**, it to be referenced from other module/project and therefore to be able to write the implementation, for example one based on Hibernate

The pom.xml file for that project/module named **01CentralRepositoryCommonBasic** has the following:

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
<artifactId>central-repository-common-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralRepositoryCommonBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
```

I have other project/module for **Spring Data**, it is named **01CentralRepositoryDataJpaBasic**, there the project has the same interface definition (package and name), but according with Spring Data JPA, it has other content, such as:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {

}
```

The pom.xml file has the following:

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
<artifactId>central-repository-data-jpa-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralRepositoryDataJpaBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
```

Until here:

- two projects
- same package
- same interfaces names (i.e: ProductRepository) but different content.

I have a third module/project named **01CentralServiceImplBasic**, it implements services definitions (interfaces) and it mandatorily needs a repository interface.

For example:

```
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
@Service("productService")
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private ProductRepository productRepository; 

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository productRepository){
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }
```

Now my pom.xml

```
    <!-- Manuel Jordan -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-service-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-repository-common-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
```

Observe I use the *central-repository-common-basic* and not *central-repository-data-jpa-basic*, both has the same package and interface.

In other module/project, named **01DataJpaPersistence**, I have the following (now working with implementations)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-repository-data-jpa-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-service-impl-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository</groupId>
                <artifactId>central-repository-common-basic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I can see through the *package explorer view* the exclusion of the **central-repository-common-basic** dependency (it do not appears) and I can see the normal inclusion of the other **central-repository-data-jpa-basic** dependency.

> Since both projects has the same package and same interface and one of
>   them has been included I think all must be fine.

Even more remember:

> central-repository-data-jpa-basic has the interface based on Spring
>   Data JPA, Spring behinds makes the implementation

But in runtime, I receive the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.manuel.jordan.model.repository.ProductRepository.save
(Lcom/manuel/jordan/domain/Product;)
Lcom/manuel/jordan/domain/Product;
```

Practically my *central-repository-data-jpa-basic* dependency has been ignored too...

**Note:** I am totally sure that Spring Data Jpa works fine, because if I create other module/project named **01CentralServiceDataJpaImplBasic** and it references directly the **central-repository-data-jpa-basic** dependency and it (01CentralServiceDataJpaImplBasic) is used how a dependency for **01DataJpaPersistence** all work fine.

I don't want have two projects with the same services implementations and just changing the repository dependency.

What is missing?

Thanks in advance.

**Alpha**:

About the requested *central-service-basic*'s dependencies

```
<groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centralservice</groupId>
<artifactId>central-service-basic</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>01CentralServiceBasic</name>
<version>01</version>
...
<dependencies>

    <!-- Manuel Jordan -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>central-domain-basic</artifactId>
        <version>01</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

It is a project/module, its purpose is to define business interfaces.

About **mvn dependency:tree** for my **01DataJpaPersistence**

```
[INFO] +- com.manuel.jordan.centralfactory:central-factory-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.manuel.jordan.centraldomain:central-domain-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.manuel.jordan.centralrepository:central-repository-data-jpa-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] +- com.manuel.jordan.centralservice:central-service-impl-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.manuel.jordan.centralservice:central-service-basic:jar:01:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |     \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
```

Comment: just to confirm you have two dependencies you are trying to exclude one, and it is still coming in classpath and not honoring <excluion> ? how do you run it ? can you try dumping runtime classpath and post it

Comment: No, it has been excluded well, the other that remains and appears in the package view explorer how a dependency (based on Spring Data JPA) in runtime is totally ignored

Comment: Can you post mvn dependency:tree for all projects? That might help since the situation seems to involve dependency conflict.

Comment: Also what about central-service-basic's dependencies

Comment: **Alpha** section included for the new requirements.